# Change order of added FeatureGraphicsLayer in GraphicsDataSet?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects

I am adding two FeatureGraphicsLayer to a GraphicDataSet like so:

```
 graphicsFunctionality.GraphicsDataSet.Tables.Add(featGraphicsLayer);
```

It looks like it puts the last one in on the very top of all the other FeatureGraphicsLayers.

I need to add one to the bottom of the GraphicsDataSet.

Is this possible?

Is there a ways to change the order of FeatureGraphicsLayers once they are in the GraphicsDataSet?

Answer (score 1):

Un-tested, un-proven, and not an expert here, but you could try something like this...

```
    graphicsMapFunctionality.GraphicsDataSet.Tables.Add(eventsFeatureGraphicsLayer)
    gdsInsertAt(eventsFeatureGraphicsLayer2, graphicsMapFunctionality,graphicsMapFunctionality.GraphicsDataSet.Tables.Count)

Protected Sub gdsInsertAt(ByVal theTableToInsert As Data.DataTable, ByVal graphicsMF As ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.Graphics.MapFunctionality, ByVal index As Integer)
    Dim tableList As List(Of Data.DataTable) = New List(Of Data.DataTable)
    For i = 0 To graphicsMF.GraphicsDataSet.Tables.Count - 1
        tableList.Insert(i, graphicsMF.GraphicsDataSet.Tables(i))
    Next
    tableList.Insert(index, theTableToInsert)
    graphicsMF.GraphicsDataSet.Tables.Clear()
    graphicsMF.GraphicsDataSet.Tables.AddRange(tableList.ToArray)
End Sub
```

This will change the order of the tables, but I'm not sure how it affects the rendering.